# Как сделать нормальный интерфейс для проекта 2D в Unity 2022

Tags: unity3d

Создал 2д проект в юнити, в итоге создался проект с таким интерфейсом(1 фото), в то время как у всех создается обычное стандартный проект с обычным всем привычным интерфейсом.(фото 2) До этого делал проект 3д, все было отлично. Много раз пересоздавал проект, даже переустанавливал юнити. Все безуспешно. Подскажите пожалуйста, может просто я криворукий и что-то не понимаю
[[image: ][1]]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чем тебе так не нормально? Ну кликни по вкладке `Game` два раза коли такой привиреда...

Answer (score 0):

Сверху слева находятся три точки, нажми на них, там ты увидишь пункт "Maximize", если возле него стоит галочка, то убери её.

Если галочки нет, придётся добавлять всё в ручную, через Window -> General
А именно Inspector, Hierarchy, Project, Scene и Console.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо. Попробую